# MySQL update a record on duplicate key update (merge)

Tags: mysql, updates, upsert

I have a table `products` with the follow schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `article_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price_cents` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `quantity` smallint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_products_unique` (`user_id`,`article_id`,`price_cents`),
  KEY `fk_products_article` (`article_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_products_article` FOREIGN KEY (`article_id`) REFERENCES `articles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_products_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Now I can do INSERT with this query:

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`user_id`,`article_id`,`price_cents`,`quantity`) 
VALUES (1,1,200,1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `price_cents`=VALUES(`price_cents`),`quantity`=quantity+VALUES(`quantity`)
```

So now I have 1 product (ID 1) with quantity 1 and price 200.
Now I insert 2 more products with:

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`user_id`,`article_id`,`price_cents`,`quantity`) 
VALUES (1,1,200,1),(1,1,199,1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `price_cents`=VALUES(`price_cents`),`quantity`=quantity+VALUES(`quantity`)
```

Now I have 2 products, one (ID 1) with quantity 2 and price 200 and the other (ID 2) with quantity 1 and price 199.

Good.

The problem comes now: I want to update the product with price 199 and set a new price to 200. What I do is:

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`id`,`user_id`,`article_id`,`price_cents`,`quantity`) 
VALUES (2,1,1,200,1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `price_cents`=VALUES(`price_cents`),`quantity`=quantity+VALUES(`quantity`)
```

and what I would like is a single product with id 1, price 200, and quantity 3, but I get `Number:0x426, Message: "Duplicate entry '1-1-200' for key 'products.idx_products_unique'` because MySQL does not delete the product with ID 2.

Is there a way to achieve this in MySQL (keep in mind that I want to perform these operations in bulk)?

Comment: The problem is that the duplicate key is in another record, so you cannot do this with a single sql statement. After detecting the dupkucate key error, you need to delete the record with 199 price and update the quantity in the 200 price row.

Comment: You have 2 unique constraints - primary key and `idx_products_unique`. If update fires due to one constraint violation, and updated values causes another constraint violation (your choice) then the query fails.

Comment: It seems abnormal to have the price as part of a unique key.  This implies that you are holding the _same_ product with _different_ prices??

Comment: @RickJames exacly

Comment: You mention doing things "in bulk".  Please elaborate and/or give an example.  Also, how many items might be in the batch?  I _think_ there might be a way to batch any number of items in 2 SQL statements (one to update, one to 'merge'), but I have not thought through the details.  (There is no automatic way to do it in a single statement.)

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe 4 statements, inside a transaction.

Comment: And will the "batch" come from hard-coded stuff like `VALUES (2,1,1,200)`?  Or from a temp table with a bunch of updates/merges to perform?

Comment: In bulk means update with a single statement many products. Like the query in the question that upsert two products (one of 200 and other of 199 cents).

Comment: Check my Answer.  If it is correct, I will delete most of my Comments; I think I was making it harder than it needed to be.

Comment: *I want to update the product with price 199 and set a new price to 200. What I do is:* I see 5 columns but 4 values. While removing 1st column everything works without error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb690443c84987915c0e438b694243e3

Comment: I've update your fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb63a0815bb0a79028dcd5ed8c53e5a7
but there is a problem: the product with id 2 with price 199 still exists. The idea is to update the price of the product with id 2 from 199 to 200 and merge it with the product with same columns that is the product with id 1.

Comment: *The idea is to update the price of the product with id 2 from 199 to 200* ??? What is the reason? ```(`user_id`,`article_id`,`price_cents`)``` for this row differs from the same expression value for the row id=1. Your logic is absolutely unclear...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `id` in the statement.  A single IODKU does the entire task:

```
INSERT INTO t  (`user_id`,`article_id`,`price_cents`,`quantity`)
    ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        quantity = quantity + VALUES(quantity)
```

Where `...` is either a batch: `VALUES (11,22,33), ...` or `SELECT (uid,aid,cents) FROM temp`.

(Optionally, get rid of `id` and upgrading the 3-column Unique index to be Primary.)

Comment: I've tried without the ID, but I get the same error.

Comment: Show me your IODKU and `CREATE TABLE` without `id`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your design does not comply with your intent.

Get rid of

UNIQUE KEY `idx_products_unique` (`user_id`,`article_id`,`price_cents`),

You can make it a non-unique index if you plan to query by it.

Also - I think you are not using the database correctly...

You should just have the records - raw data with the values.

You should get the value you are trying to aggregate as a view or a query (use group by).

Answer (score -1):

You should use a merge statement, **For example**:
You have two tables, `Products` and `Products info`
You want to merge both but don't want to include duplicates.
Use the Following

```
MERGE Products P
USING Products_Info PI
ON (PI.ProductID = P.ProductID)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE SET
P.Product_Name = PI.Product_Name,
P.Cost = PI.Cost
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT (Product_ID, Product_Name, Cost/quantity)
VALUES(PI.ProductID,PI.Product_Name,PI.Cost)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
THEN DELETE;
```

Comment: The question is tagged as MySQL-related. There is no MERGE in MySQL.